# Discord - Get user's server nickname from id

Tags: python, discord

How do I get the server nickname of a user from id using `discord.Client()`?

```
user = await client.fetch_user(ID)
print(user.name) # works
print(user.display_name) # works
print(user.nick) # does not work
print(user.avatar_url) # works
```

The value of `user.display_name` and `user.name` are same, both are printing the username, could be a bug?

Is there any way to convert `discord.user.User` to `discord.member.Member`?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, such as how are you fetching the user details and what error messages are you receiving.

Comment: i'm fetching the user object from the user id `await client.fetch_user()`, the error says `'user' has no object called 'nick'`

Comment: Reference to this doc: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#id7 there is no `nick` attribute for user

Comment: i already know there is no nick attribute for user, my question is how do i get it some other way

Comment: Have u tried `display_name`?

Comment: @GhostOps i have already mentioned that in my code

Comment: @Arghadip i mean, pls put some sample input and results in your question if u still didnt get any answer. ..

Comment: i cannot just made up my own code, this is what i've done so far and it doesn't provide me the `user.nick` that's all i know

Comment: `User` object is not the same as `Member` object. To get `Member` object, you need to use `guild.get_member(ID)`. You can get guild object using `client.get_guild(ID)`. If needed, you can also loop through all guilds using `for guild in client.guilds:`

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the following answers your question:

```
name = user.name
guilds = await client.fetch_guilds().flatten()
for guild in guilds:
    if guild.get_member_named(name):
        member = guild.get_member_named(name)
        print(member.nick)
```

Comment: It never surpasses this line `if guild.get_member_named(name):` the `guild.get_member_named(name)` returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution by converting the User object to Member.

```
member = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, 'STRING_ID')
```